# Combining macros generate errors

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, avr

I want to generate the name of an AVR interrupt vector with the C preprocessor and with a given interface name. So I have this configuration file (`Config.h`) which is included to another header file.

```
#define INTERFACE                   C, 0
#define BAUD                        19200
```

and this macro to get the ISR name

```
#include "Config.h"
#define ISR_NAME(Name, Vector)      USART ## C0 ## _ ## Vector ## _vect
```

This macro is used in my code

```
#include "Config.h"

ISR(ISR_NAME(INTERFACE, RXC))
{
    // Some stuff
}
```

and it works pretty fine. But the name of the interface should set according to the given `INTERFACE` and for this I change the macro `ISR_NAME` to the following

```
#include "Config.h"
#define CATENATE(Prefix, Index)             Prefix ## Index
#define ISR_NAME(Name, Vector)              USART ## CATENATE(Name) ## _ ## Vector ## _vect
```

With using the macro like before

```
#include "Config.h"

ISR(ISR_NAME(INTERFACE, RXC))
{
    // Some code
}
```

This solution produce a loot of warnings and errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File                                Line
Message     in expansion of macro 'ISR_NAME'                                ...
Message     in expansion of macro 'ISR_NAME'                                ...
Message     in expansion of macro 'ISR_NAME'                                ...
Message     in expansion of macro 'INTERFACE'                               ...
Message     in expansion of macro 'INTERFACE'                               ...
Error       expected ')' before numeric constant    File                    ...
Error       expected ')' before numeric constant    File                    ...
Error       recipe for target 'File.o' failed   File                        ...
Error       pasting ")" and "_" does not give a valid preprocessing token   ...
```

What is going wrong here? Why does this extra macro produces this errors?

Comment: Your `CATENATE` is using only one parameter (`Name`), but it requires two parameters (according your definition).

Comment: So the `INTERFACE` define doesn´t contain two parameters? I thought `C, 0` will count as two values with one `define`.

Comment: Just to be sure, could you write in the second to last block, how you used ISR_NAME (which gave you the error)? From last comment I *assume* something like `ISR_NAME(INTERFACE, 123)` (but I do not like to assume)

Comment: Sure. I will edit my answer shortly. But just as an information. The macro generate an error too if I use `CATENATE(C, 0)` instead of `CATENATE(Name)`.

Comment: No `INTERFACE` counts as one pre-processor token, which will later gets expanded into two values. Why function-like macro dependency chains is something quite evil. They almost always end up as an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: @Lundin at which point does the preprocessor split it into two arguments? Because this behaviour is maximum weird..
Writing `MACRO(C, 0)` is okay but when I write `MACRO(INTERFACE)` it isn´t okay, because `MACRO` needs two arguments and not one...

Comment: Sometimes you can resolve these issues by passing your functor macro and your arguments macro as two parameters to another macro that simply invokes functor with arguments. This extra layer of macro allows the arguments to be expanded to multiple arguments as you want. As mentioned by others, this is all very messy and prone to mysterious failure, generally when you try and invoke that wrapper from another macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is "clearly" described by this error message

```
Error       pasting ")" and "_" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

which applies to this expansion:

```
USART ## CATENATE(Name) ## _ ## Vector ## _vect
```

("Clearly" here is a bit of a joke. The error is clearly described, but you need to sift through a lot of chaff to find the informative error message.)

When you look at that line, you see `CATENATE(Name)` being concatenated to `_`. But that's not what the preprocessor sees, because the token pasting operator `##` is applied *before* rescanning the replacement text for further macro expansions. What the preprocessor sees is `) ## _`, which, as it points out, does not produce a legal token. (The preprocessor also joined `USART ## CATENATE` producing the legal but undefined token `USARTCATENATE`, which it didn't bother to warn you about. But that presumably has other consequences which produce other errors.)

If you want to token paste the result of a macro expansion, whether it is a simple macro expansion or a function-like macro expansion, you need to use an indirect token-pasting macro, like your `CATENATE`:

```
#define ISR_NAME(Name, Vector) \
  CATENATE(USART, CATENATE(CATENATE(Name), CATENATE(_, CATENATE(Vector, _vect))))
```

Of course, that will fully macro-expand both `Name` and `Vector`, which might not be exactly what you wanted. To get what you want, you need to be clear about the order of macro expansion for function-like macros which use the `#` or `##` operators:

1. Macro parameters are substituted with the arguments from the call, except for those parameters which appear as the argument to an `#` or `##` operator. The arguments are fully-expanded before this substitution.
2. The `##` and `#` operators are applied.

   - `#` *must* be followed by a macro parameter name; the corresponding argument is transformed into a string literal without any macro expansions being performed on the argument.
   - If a parameter appears before or after `##`, that parameter is substituted by its corresponding argument, again without any macro expansions being performed. (If a substituted parameter corresponds to an empty argument, then a special empty placeholder is inserted.) Then every occurrence of two tokens (or placeholders) separated by `##` is replaced with a new token representing the concatenation of the two original tokens.
3. Finally, the resulting substitution text is rescanned for macro expansions.

Function-like macro arguments are identified during the (re-)scan, which is why `CATENATE(INTERFACE)` works as expected (except on non-compliant C preprocessors, such as historic MSVC implementations) inside a macro definition, but not at the top level.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. I add a second layer to that macro and the macros working fine with this extra layer.